# how to get the source of a website in (Windows phone 7.1 - 8.0) C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

So in a nutshell I want to get the source of any website in Windows Phone 8 SDK using C#. When I put this code in regular C# Visual Studio it works fine, but when I put this code in Windows Phone 8 SDK (C#) the compiler gives me an error on the code

`HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();`

Specifically on the `GetResponse()`

So is there another way to get the source of a website without using the `GetResonse()` or that line, or just a way to get the HTML code of a website in Windows Phone 8 SDK

Code examples would be greatly appreciated

### The code:

```
string inputurl = "https://www.any_website_url.com/";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(inputurl);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader urlinputreader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string urlsourcecode = urlinputreader.ReadToEnd();
String websitesourcecode = urlsourcecode;
```

Comment: I believe Joachim Isaksson's answer is the correct one, but I would also like to point out that you always, ALWAYS need to include the error.  The only thing you gave us is: "the compiler gives me an error."  I suspect the actual error would have immediately revealed the problem.

Comment: @BTownTKD Thanks for the advice, im fairly new to stack overflow

Answer (score 2):

HttpWebRequest in WPx is asynchronous, and since GetResponse is a synchronous method, it's not available/should not be used.

What you need to do is to call [BeginGetResponse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse(v=vs.95).aspx) with a callback that will be called when the response is available, something similar to;

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(inputurl);

// MyCallback will be called when the response is available.
IAsyncResult result=
      (IAsyncResult) request.BeginGetResponse(
                          new AsyncCallback(MyCallback), request);
```

A more complete sample is available [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devfish/archive/2011/04/07/httpwebrequest-fundamentals-windows-phone-services-consumption-part-2.aspx).

Comment: Im still a little confused, I tried putting it in but I got a compiler error on "RequestState" and frankly I looked at the website, I'm frankly a little confused on how I can make it totally work.

Comment: @user1564622 Ah, sorry, I messed up the code a little, cleaned up the sample. Also, for a somewhat simplified experience, you could try to use [WebClient](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devfish/archive/2011/04/06/webclient-windows-phone-services-consumption-part-1.aspx).

Comment: One last question I have is I get an error on "MyCallBack" im a little confused, should I have a void that it goes to or what? (Sorry for all of the follow-up questions)

Comment: @user1564622 It's a normal function that will be called when the request is ready, declared `private void MyCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)`. If you look at the linked sample, you'll see more in detail how it works.